# Matplotlib plot size/legend issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I'm trying to place the legend in the space underneath a matplotlib plot. I'm creating each subplot with a unique identifier then using plt.figure() to adjust the size of the plot. When I specify a plot size, the space around the plot disappears (the PNG tightens the layout around the plot). Here's my code:

```
        fig = plt.subplot(111)
        plt.figure(111,figsize=(3,3))
        plots = []
        legend = []
        #fig.set_xlim([0, 20])
        #fig.set_ylim([0, 1])
        #ticks = list(range(len(k_array)))
        #plt.xticks(ticks, k_array)
        plt.plot(k_array, avgNDCG, 'red')
        legend.append("eco overall F1")
        if data_loader.GSQb:
            legend.append("GSQ F1")
            plt.plot(k_array, avgGSQNDCG, 'orange')
        if data_loader.BSQb:
            legend.append("BSQ F1")
            plt.plot(k_array, avgBSQNDCG, 'purple')
        if data_loader.GWQb:
            legend.append("GWQ F1")
            plt.plot(k_array, avgGWQNDCG, 'black')
        if data_loader.BWQb:
            legend.append("BWQ F1")
            plt.plot(k_array, avgBWQNDCG, 'green')
        if data_loader.GAQb:
            legend.append("GAQ F1")
            plt.plot(k_array, avgGAQNDCG, 'blue')
        fig.legend(legend, loc='center', bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0, .7, -2),fontsize='xx-small')
        plt.savefig("RARE " + metaCat + " best avg NDCG scores")
```

When I comment out `plt.figure(111,figsize=(3,3))`, the white space underneath and around the plot is visible:
[image]

But when I uncomment it:

[image]

Please help me understand how I can modify the plotsize, legend and layout spacing to make it look more like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWJAB.png) but with a bigger plot.

Comment: Why not add the legend to the axes instead of the figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you add labels to your plot functions, then you won't have to supply legend() with handles and labels - this is more convenient.
2. I would recommend using a loop structure instead of multiple if statements.
3. Regarding the legend, using ncol parameter is going to help you a lot here. You may find the matplotlib documentation [legend tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) helpful
4. If you're working with multiple subplots with different sizes, then I'd recommend using [gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html), otherwise just use [plt.subplots()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) with ncols and nrows parameters. For example:

   fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=5, figsize=(12,12))
   axes = axes.flatten() #this results in a 1d array of 10 axes

I simulated your data and implemented what I think you are looking for below.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#simulate data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1, 2, 3]})
for i in range(11):     
    df['Line_' + str(i)] = np.random.random_sample(3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,2.5))

# Change x and y values for troubleshooting purposes
ax.plot(df.x, df.Line_1, 'red', label='eco overall F1')

# This would be a good place to implement a for loop 
# Change all conditions to true for troubleshooting purposes
if True:
    ax.plot(df.x, df.Line_1, 'orange', label='GSQ F1')
if True:
    ax.plot(df.x, df.Line_2, 'purple', label='BSQ F1')
if True:
    ax.plot(df.x, df.Line_3, 'black', label='GWQ F1')
if True:
    ax.plot(df.x, df.Line_4, 'green', label='BWQ F1')
if True:
    ax.plot(df.x, df.Line_5, 'blue', label='GAQ F1')

legend = ax.legend(ncol=4, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,-0.5), loc='lower center', edgecolor='w')
hide_spines = [ax.spines[x].set_visible(False) for x in ['top','right']]
```

Comment: getting a blank graph with this code @Coup (given that the NDCG arrays are not empty)          
        ```fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 2.5))
        if data_loader.GSQb:
            ax.plot(k_array, avgGSQNDCG,'orange', label='GSQ NDCG')
        if data_loader.BSQb:
            ax.plot(k_array, avgBSQNDCG,'purple', label='BSQ NDCG')
        legend = ax.legend(ncol=4, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, .8), loc='lower center', edgecolor='w')
        plt.savefig("RARE " + metaCat + " best avg NDCG scores")```

Comment: hard to say, but most likely an issue with true/false if statements or with x/y variables. Try making 'if True' to see if that plots it otherwise try some basic x and y values or look at your data to see what's going on. Then try simplifying what you're plotting.